# Is Future.delayed removed in Dart SDK version 1.9.0-dev.8.0?

Tags: dart, dart-async

Future.delayed no longer available, is this removed by accident or planned?

Comment: I see it in the latest dev docs: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async.Future#id_Future-delayed  Your question might be better for misc@dartlang.org

Comment: `Future.delayed` should still be there, so if you can't see it, there must be a problem somewhere. Try filing an issue on the [dart bug tracker](http://dartbug.com/new) that states what you are doing (example code which is failing is great) and what is happening (how it crashes).

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry. It's still there.

https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/sdk/lib/async/future.dart#L224

Answer (score 1):

From the [bug report](http://dartbug.com/22606), it seems most likely that you are calling `Future.delayed` as if it was a static function. It's a constructor, so it needs a `new` in front of the call: `new Future.delayed(duration, computation)`.